# Discord.py, dropdown menu dont work with "Interaction failed"

Tags: python, discord.py

Im still on the beginner level of python, and discord bot development. Here is a piece of code that trough API, searches wikipedia and the lists all the hits to a dropdown menu, where you can pick one and it sends a link to the page of the article. I ran into a problem where after the pick discords sends this message: `Interaction failed`.
Here the py code:

````
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

discord.api_key = open("token.txt", "r").read().strip("\n")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

xxx_WIKIPEDIA_API_URL = "xxx"

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler(),  
        logging.FileHandler("bot.log")  
    ]
)

logging.info("Infó üzenet")
logging.error("Hiba üzenet")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} bejelentkezett")

@bot.command(name="wiki")
async def wikipedia(ctx, *args):
    search_query = " ".join(args)
    params = {
        "action": "opensearch",
        "format": "json",
        "search": search_query,
        "limit": 5,
    }
    response = requests.get(xxx_WIKIPEDIA_API_URL, params=params)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        api_data = response.json()
        
        if len(api_data) >= 4 and len(api_data[1]) > 0:
            titles = api_data[1]

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Keresés eredménye: {search_query}", color=0x00FF00)
            embed.description = "Válassz egy elemet a legördülő menüből!"

            
            options = [discord.SelectOption(label=title) for title in titles]
            select = Select(
                placeholder="Válassz egy elemet",
                options=options,
                custom_id="wikipedia_select",
            )

            
            view = View()
            view.add_item(select)

            message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
        else:
            await ctx.send('Nincs találat a xxx Wikipédián.')
    else:
        logging.error(f"Hiba: HTTP státuszkód {response.status_code}")
        await ctx.send("Hiba történt az API kéréskor.")

@bot.event
async def on_select_option(interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id == "wikipedia_select":
        selected_option = interaction.values[0]
        
        
        logging.info(f"Selected option: {selected_option}")
        
        
        link = f"xxx{selected_option.replace(' ', '_')}"
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Wikipédia Link", color=0x00FF00)
        embed.description = link
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

bot.run(discord.api_key)```
````

Comment: Hi! Can you tell us if is there any errors in your code? And a discord.py + python version. 
From this I can only think of instead of `Select()` use `discord.ui.Select()` *no additional import needed*

Comment: Hey! Python version: 3.10 Discord.py version: 2.3.2. No i dont think the code has errors at least the terminal is not giving me an errormessage. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean your code seems correct besides that `Select()`. Instead that try and use `discord.ui.Select()`.
If you want to we can talk in Hungarian on discord. @rexy.py

Comment: There are no such events as `on_select_option` in discord.py. Please see the official [dropdown](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py#L9-L29) example for how to correctly use select menus.